# Gravitational time dilation - Kip Thorne example

Tags: general-relativity, doppler-effect

[image][image]

Please find in the images an example from Kip Thorne’s book ‘black holes & time warps’ on Gravitational Time Dilation. I do not understand the last sentences where the doppler effect results in the gravitational time dilation conclusion. I perceive it in this sense more as velocity time dilation?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like velocity time dilation. If the floor clock was also sending a signal up, by the same argument, the ceiling (falling) clock would see floor clock's pulses more closely spaced. Which is due to relative velocity. There may be some other context that the author may have established before writing these pages.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the equivalence principle? If we say 2 ‘seconds’ passed in ceiling clock time and thus 2 light signals were emitted. In the floor clock perhaps 1,5 second passed and the signals were received; i.e slower time due to doppler effect. Equivalence states that the acceleration in a small gravity abscent inertial frame = gravity in a small free falling frame? For it to work both ways as you suggested (relativity) gravity has to come in play in stead of relative velocity difference? I’m quite new in the topic so please correct my reasoning if necessary

Comment: If you'd really like help, it'd be greatly appreciated for you to copy the text into the post, rather than posting unsearchable images of text instead.

Comment: Hi Kyle, my apologies. Will see if I can copy the text in later, however I think the others can see the pictures?

Comment: @JurreStassen the issue isn't whether people can or cannot see the image but that the words *in* the image cannot be read by computers, which means (a) search engines are unable to display this post as a result for someone interested in this section and (b) screen readers can't parse what is displayed (there are probably other issues, but these are m two should highlight the issue with posting screenshots of text).

Answer (score 1):

This is a thought experiment. The idea is to develop intuition from a situation you understand and transfer it to one you don’t (yet).

Yes, for the falling clocks you see a velocity based effect. That’s right!

The next point to realize is that, by construction, the *non-moving* clocks see the same offset. Why are they seeing different times, even though they’re not moving? Ah, because of gravity!

And that’s the result Einstein wanted to show.

Comment: Thank you, Bob! This does make sense to me now. Can I from your argument relate this to the equivalence principle? (Gravity in a small free falling inertial frame is equal to acceleration in a small inertial frame (excl gravity)?

Comment: @JurreStassen the equivalence principal (EP) is a *local* equivalence between gravity and an *accelerated* frame. That’s not really what you have here, where you’re trying to create an analogy between two specific free-failing (hence individually inertial) *separated* bodies and two bodies at different gravitational potentials. Instead of the EP, this is an example of “all the different ways of thinking have to lead to the same physical result” equivalence, related to the principal that reality is independent of calculation.

Comment: Thank you, I was misinterpreting the fact that it was just a thought example to show that there are different ways of thinking (being gravity and velocity here) to come at the samd conclusion being time dilation. Thank you for the correction on the EV, sounds more logically to me now

Answer (score 0):

Whether the time dilation involved in the described situation is called "gravitational time dilation" or "velocity time dilation" is merely a matter of semantics. "Gravitational time dilation" and "velocity time dilation" aren't *in general* clearly separable, physically distinct phenomena.

*All* time dilation is due to the relative velocity between two inertial frames of reference. In a curved spacetime, it isn't possible to define an inertial frame of reference that covers all of spacetime; instead, an inertial frame of reference can only be defined and used locally in the vicinity of a given event. The right way to compare a pair of inertial frames of reference in use at two different events is to [parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) a frame of reference in use at one event to the other event along a curve. That's basically what's being done in the situation in the book; an inertial frame of reference at the ceiling at the moment the string is cut is being parallel transported along the ceiling clock's [world line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) to the event at which the ceiling clock hits the floor. But importantly, the inertial frame of reference you get at event B by parallel transporting an inertial frame of reference at event A along a curve from A to B in general depends on which curve you choose to use.

The scalar [gravitational potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#General_relativity) used in Newtonian gravity is an unnatural construct in general relativity, but it can be defined in an approximate sense in a region of spacetime involving only a [weak gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearized_gravity) from slow-moving sources (such as anywhere in the solar system), or in a [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime), spherically symmetric spacetime if you adopt a convention to only consider a restricted set of curves. In regions of spacetime in which it works well to speak of a gravitational potential, you can define "gravitational time dilation" as something that's dependent only on the difference between the gravitational potential between two events, instead of depending on a choice of curve between the events. But in regions of spacetime in which it doesn't work well to try to define a gravitational potential, it becomes necessary to specify the curve used for parallel transporting an inertial frame of reference for comparison purposes, and how much of the resulting time dilation is "gravitational time dilation" versus "velocity time dilation" becomes ambiguous.